# Cross Apply vs Case statements when dealing with calculations in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there an advantage of using Cross apply over case statements? For example as below I have a number of columns I need to do calculations on, **is it inefficient to use cross apply to achieve this or is there no performance difference?**

```
SELECT * from myTable
cross apply
(
  select test1 =
  CASE  
    WHEN Price <> '' AND Cost <> 0 and 
      Cast(Cost As float) <> -1 THEN Cost + Price                           
    WHEN Price <> '' AND Cost = 0 THEN bestPrice   
    WHEN Price <> '' AND Cost = -1 THEN CAST(Cost AS varchar(20))
  END 
) as test1  
cross apply
(
  select Handling = round(((Price * 1.2) + 2.5) / 0.85, 2)
) as Handling                              
WHERE (accuracy > 0 and Total <> -1)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, why the votes down?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I edited your question to make the question a little more clear. I suspect that this has been voted down because of that. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @usr agreed, the initial question did not include enough details so it was probably down voted because of that.

Comment: For me the data types smell. You cast `Cost` to `float` to test for `-1` and also cast it to `varchar(20)` for the return value so `Cost + Price` is also assumed to be implicitly `varchar(20)`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance difference. You can verify this by looking at the execution plans of both variants.

A cross-apply in this pattern is just a "Compute Scalar". The query optimizer is smart about this.